# Problem with installing Ubuntu, stuck on very first boot screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my PC, I have already got Windows 10 on my PC so I tried installing Ubuntu on a new entirely different SSD, I followed this guide:

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

But I run into some sort of error on the very first boot screen. 
Pic of the error:

[image: https://imgur.com/Gi5pq2K]

There is also some sort of weird screen glitch on the right side of the screen.

[image: https://imgur.com/i9ZKWWz]

I have tried booting with two different flash drives and I have also tried manually giving the flash drive boot priority through the BIOS.

Also, I'm a complete newbie when it comes to anything Linux.

Comment: i also unplugged the windows ssd before trying to install ubuntu

Comment: This is a filesystem related error. Not allowing Windows 10 to shut down cleanly might be a reason. Try booting to Windows 10 and normally shutting down afterwords. Then boot to Ubuntu and see if it boots cleanly.

Comment: shutting it down completely fixed that problem,but now it says "failed to start journal service" whenevr i try to install ubuntu